# Offline Pages with Service-Worker React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am totally new to service-workers! I am having a react site running in the localhost and about to be deployed. I am following the code specified [here](https://gist.github.com/camwhite/2f33f7c33e2495b01614f209399703ee).

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
)

export default function register () {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location)
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`

      if (!isLocalhost) {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl)
      } else {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl)
      }
    })
  }
}

function registerValidSW (swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.')
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    })
}

function checkValidServiceWorker (swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload()
          })
        })
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl)
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      )
    })
}

export function unregister () {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister()
    })
  }
}
```

This only works in Production but, I want the offline-site to run in the `localhost` and also cache only the base route ie `/`. I don't want to cache any other pages. 
Any help is greatly appreciated ! 
Thanks!

Comment: The service worker provided by cra doesn't work in development mode, as specified in its docs. :) as caching stuffs in development would cause issues. You would want your changes to hot-reload during development. If you want to test caching, just build the app, don't deploy it and test it using a static server like 'serve'. :)

Comment: Thanks! How can I cache only the `/` (base) page?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Workbox will cache all the js files, which will include every components. So everything get's cached.

Comment: But why would you even need that?

Comment: The thing is that I have:- `/` `/settings` routes (pages) and more coming... I only want the `/` page to be offline. I don't want the other pages to be offline-working. If it is not an issue (not taking much memory or something) then it's okay !

Comment: Why do you want other pages to not be offline? You want to make api calls in them perhaps, you don't need them to not be offline for that. I think you're taking a wrong approach to that. Tell me more what you need to do in that settings page.

Comment: Yes! As you said, I want to make 1 or 2 api calls from the server in the `/settings` page. So when the user visits the `/settings` page, I only want to show a custom  "No Internet Page". But when they visit just the `/` page, I want to render the normal `/` page.

Comment: You can make api calls, without making settings page offline.

Comment: No..No. I was talking about the scenario when the user is offline. When the user is offline and visits the /settings page, I only want to show a custom "No Internet Page". But when they visit just the / page, I want to render the normal / page

Comment: Can we make api calls from server even when the user is offline ?

Comment: you can make api calls even when he is offline, but it fails, and when it fails you can do something like show an alert like 'Hey, you have to be online for this' or sumthing like that. Or you can also check for 'navigator.onLine' to check if the user is offline, and render your 'U are offline' component. A pseudocode I've posted as an answer, see if it helps you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you could do.

```
//this is your settings component
export default function Settings(props) {
  const [offline, setOffline] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!navigator.onLine) setOffline(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
    {offline && (
       <div>You are offline please connect to the internet</div>
       <button onClick={() => window.location.reload(true)}>Refresh</button>
    )}
    {!offline && (
      <div>This is my actual settings page</div>
    )}
    </>
  );
}
```

There you go, you have conditional rendering of your settings, on the basis of the user being offline. Or you could also try alerting the user when the fetch fails(the user is offline). Like below:

```
export default function Settings(props) {
  const handleAPICall = () => {
    fetch(YOUR_API_ENDPOINT).then(res => res.json()).then(data => useData(data)).catch(err => {
      setOffline(true);
    });
  }
  return (
    <>
     {offline && (
       <Alert timeout={'3s'}>You are offline please connect to the internet</Alert>
     )}
     <div>
        <p>This is my actual settings page</p>
        <button onClick={handleAPICall}>Fetch data</button>
     </div>
    </>
  );
    </>
  );
}
```

I hope you find one of these approaches applicable to you. See, making only a part of your web app offline was never the right approach to your problem in the first place. Sometimes it gets hard to ask the right questions because you yourself don't know what you want. But we have to keep grinding.

Comment: Thanks! But what can I do to show a custom "No Internet Page" ?. Like what you see when you visit https://meet.google.com/ without internet.

Comment: @AjitKumar It's your choice. You can do anything when the 'offline' state goes true. I think the first approach is more suited for you. In that, I have displayed a div with 'You are offline' written, you can design it to be anything you want. However you wanna blame the user for being offline is your choice my man.

Comment: Ooh! no I don't wanna blame them. Thanks !

Comment: I read this article and I was confused... https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Comment: Thanks! But I stumbled upon this issue on service-workers. Can you help me in this ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68450454/14326852