# Custom Service Worker in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I was following a tutorial on creating custom service-worker in React. I got it complete but it is not working as expected. When I visit the page offline, it only renders the default "No Internet" page of Google. 
Here is my code: 
`public/customWorker.js`:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

`src/sw.js`:

```
workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("install");
});
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  console.log("activate");
});

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest || []);
```

`src/serviceWorker.js`:

```
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === "localhost" ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === "[::1]" ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/customWorker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === "installed") {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                "New content is available and will be used when all " +
                  "tabs for this page are closed."
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log("Content is cached for offline use.");

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf("javascript") === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        "No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode."
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

`config.js`: (in the root of the project)

```
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require("workbox-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.plugins = config.plugins.map((plugin) => {
    if (plugin.constructor.name === "GenerateSW") {
      return new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.InjectManifest({
        swSrc: "./src/sw.js",
        swDest: "service-worker.js",
      });
    }
    return plugin;
  });
  return config;
};
```

`package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "react-app-rewired start",
 "build": "react-app-rewired build",
 "test": "react-app-rewired test",
 "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
},
```

I ran `npm run build` and saw the served site in `localhost:5000`. For the first visit, it prints:
[image]

For the second visit:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thank You!

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example for this issue? Github repo or a codesandbox link